# PHP mailto: variable with faicon inline

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

this code is suppose to see if the ACF variable is empty if not prints
html code of globe fa icon with mailto: variable called mail
yet its not working any ideas?

---

```
<?php 
if((the_field('Email'))!=""){
    $mail = the_field('Email');
   echo '<a href="mailto:'.$mail.'"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i></a>'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to find out what exactly is in `$mail` before you try to echo it. Try adding a `print_r($mail);` to find out. Perhaps it isn't `=""`, but is `=" "` instead. Which would still not give the results that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the basic thing there is the difference between get_field and the_field.

the_field print the data and get_field required echo to print the value. 
Assuming the meta key name is Email.
Use below code

```
  <?php 
if(get_field('Email')!=""){
    $mail = get_field('Email');
   echo '<a href="mailto:'.$mail.'"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i></a>'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you that actually worked didn't realize the difference before thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get the question but can you try:

```
<?php 
if((the_field('Email'))!=""){
    $mail = the_field('Email');
   echo '<a href="mailto:'.$mail.'"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x">'.$mail.'</i></a>'; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

as i can see the_field is a function and this function return a mail caracters so the return about the_fileld('email') is Null, i think that mean your problem is into this function.